# Rails server not running but app is still working on browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

Earlier today I had issues starting my server on RubyMine due to and error stating that another server running. I've come across this before and knew that I needed to delete the `server.pid` file in the `temp\pids` directory. Great the server started to run again on RubyMine... however now when I make changes to the code, they do not appear on the browser side.

I shutdown my server on RubyMine and noticed that the app was still running on the browser. I don't believe it's a RubyMine issue because when I exit out of RubyMine the app is still running.

I'm all out of ideas. What am I missing? It's as if a ghost server is running.

Comment: Deleting the PID file doesn't shut off the other server; restart RubyMine and/or the machine.

Comment: The file has the id of the process, you use that as the argument for a kill command, or to find it in a gui with a kill option.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thank you. Just exiting RubyMine didn't solve it, but restarting my machine worked. If you would like to submit an answer, I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the PID file won't shut down the server; it just records the PID for use in a `kill` command (or its equivalent under whatever you're running).

You should be able to find the process by looking for RubyMine-, Ruby-, or Rails-related processes in (some process viewer), and it'd be easier if the IDE was shut down.

If restarting the IDE itself doesn't solve the problem (without the PID file it might not know how to shut down the server) then a machine restart certainly will.